# Failed in retrieve data from AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am a beginner at react-native.
I trying to retrieve data that stored from screen1.js in Screen2.js but I failed.

I have import Asyncstorage from react-native for both .js

This how I store variable from screenone.js :

```
class screenone extends Component {
  state = {
      oldpin: '000000',
      newpin: '',
      secpin: '',
     };

  onPressButton = () => {
      if (this.state.newpin == this.state.secpin) {
        this.setState(
            { oldpin: this.state.newpin },
             async() => await this.storeData());
      }
       else {
        ToastAndroid.show("Password Unmatched", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      }
    }

   storeData = async () =>{
        const {oldpin} = this.state;
        let  pin : oldpin;
        try{
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('mypin',pin);
            ToastAndroid.show("Password Changed", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        }
        catch (err){
            console.warn(err)
        }}
....
```

This is how I trying to retrieve data in screentwo.js:

```
class screentwo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.onComplete = this.onComplete.bind(this);
this.state = {
  pin: ''
};
}

retrieveData = async (mypin) => {
  try {
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(mypin);
    if (value !== null) {
      console.log(value);
      this.setState({
      pin: value})
    }
   } catch (error) {
      console.warn(err)
   }
}

onComplete(inputtedPin, clear) {
  retrieveData();
  if (inputtedPin !== this.state.pin) {
    ToastAndroid.show("Incorrect Pin", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    clear();
  } else {
    ToastAndroid.show("Pin is correct", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
  }}
  ....
```

Error:

```
Reference Error: ReferenceError:Can't find variable:retrieveData
```

Am I using the right way to stored and retrieve data?
Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I can see with your code.

Firstly the `retrieveData()` function. It is asynchronous and should be called with `await` also you are getting the error: `Reference Error: ReferenceError:Can't find variable:retrieveData` because you haven't used `this`

So ideally you should call it `await this.retrieveData();`

There are a few more issues with this function. You use the parameter `mypin` but don't seem to pass any parameter to the function when you call it. Fixing this issue you should call `retreiveData()` like this:

`await this.retrieveData('mypin');`

Or you could remove passing the paramater altogether, which I will show how to do in my refactor below.

Finally you call `retreiveData` every time you check the `inputtedPin` this isn't that efficient, it is `asynchronous` so it may take some time, and secondly it also takes time for the `setState` function to complete, which means that the state may not have updated in time when you go to check it against the `inputtedPin`, meaning that you are checking the `inputtedPin` against the wrong value.

## Code Refactor

This is how I would refactor your component.

1. Refactor `retrieveData` so that it no longer takes a parameter and the key is hardcoded in the `.getItem`
2. In the `componentDidMount` get the value of the pin from AsyncStorage and save it to state.
3. Remove the `retrieveData` call from `onComplete`

Here is the refactor

```
retrieveData = async () => { // parameter have been removed
  try {
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('mypin'); // notice I am now passing the key as a string not as a parameter
    if (value !== null) {
      console.log(value);
      this.setState({ pin: value })
    }
   } catch (error) {
      console.warn(err)
   }
}

// here we call the refactored retrievedData which will set the state. 
async componentDidMount () {
  await this.retrieveData();
}

onComplete(inputtedPin, clear) {
  // we remove the call to retrieveData as we have already gotten the pin in the componentDidMount
  if (inputtedPin !== this.state.pin) {
    ToastAndroid.show("Incorrect Pin", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    clear();
  } else {
    ToastAndroid.show("Pin is correct", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I have changed the code according to the code given. But the value i receive is the word "oldpin" but not the pin"000000". What is the error in the storeData in screenone.js?

Comment: Then when you are storing the value for `'mypin'` you must be storing it incorrectly. Check what you are storing in `AsyncStorage` in the `storeData` function.  I notice the line `let pin : oldpin` why is there a colon between these? Shouldn't there be an equals sign making it `let pin = oldpin`?

Comment: Seem like I make a simple mistake. Thank you for helping to solve the error. It's work now.

Answer (score 0):

only replace

```
retrieveData();
```

to

```
this.retrieveData();
```

Comment: I can't get the value from the screenone. Is that the way I retrieve having the problem?

Comment: try use **await this.retrieveData('mypin');**

Comment: I want to store the pin "000000" in the asyncstorage but i stored the word "oldpin". May I know what the mistake I made in the storeData() in screenone.js?

Answer (score 0):

When you call async method from a caller method that method also become async Try prefix 
async onComplete () { await this.retrieveData() }